# How to select only the inner face of a mesh object?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

I'm brand new to blender and I'm trying to make a glass bowl filled with a static "liquid" (just another mesh object). So I have a solidified mesh bowl made, but when I try to select the inner face of the bowl so that I can duplicate it to make my "liquid" object, it selects both the inner and outer faces of the object, instead of just the inner face.

I've been trying things and just don't know how to select ONLY the inner face. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize if it's obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've got the solidify modifier on, that's just a virtual face relative to the original mesh. Apply the solidify modifier and then you should be able to select only the inner faces.

Comment: oh wow, I didn't realize you had to "apply" a modifier like that to make the features final. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved it. :-)